# How do I add :delegated to a Docker volume I've inherited?

Tags: macos, performance, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose file where I am inheriting another image using `image: mysql:5.7.12`. That image mounts a volume to `/var/lib/mysql` where it persists the database to disk. I'd like to make it so that it mounts to `/var/lib/mysql:delegated` to improve performance of the mount point, since it's very slow on Mac OSX.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: What's the specific problem you're encountering?  You should be able to change the `docker-compose.yml` file to say what you want it to.  (You might consider a named volume to work around the MacOS performance issues, since you can't do anything useful with the MySQL database files even if you have them on the host system.)

Comment: The problem is performance. `/var/lib/mysql` being cached it making it sync with the Mac filesystem, which is slow. Like I said, this is easy if I were defining the volume myself, but since the volume is coming from a parent image, I don't know how to override the settings and make it `delegated`.

Comment: The `docker-compose.yml` file should define the `volumes:` that get used.  If you don't have those and use the implicit anonymous volume from the image, you can mount your choice of content on `/var/lib/mysql` and it will override the default.  (But, the anonymous volume will be purely inside Docker space and won't have the MacOS bind-mount performance penalty.)

Comment: Ahh got it, if the existing anonymous volume isn't bind-mounted then the question is moot. Sad, I was hoping to speed things up, my database is running slow as molasses.